# when I am logged in, how redirect to home page in react-router?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

```
<Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" render={() => (
                AUTH ? (
                    AUTH == "1" ?
                        <NormalPage />
                        :
                        <AdminPage />
                ) : (
                        <Redirect to="/login" />
                    )
            )} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        </Switch>
</Router>
```

I write the code like this. when AUTH is undefined, the page will redirect to login page.
But what should I write the code in login page when I logged in, I want to back to home page. Now, when I logged in, I use window.location.href = "/" to back to home page. But I think this is bad method. Tips: my first language isn't English, so sorry :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.props.history.push("/")` inside the login page. It has the same function as `window.location.href = "/"`, but in react router's way.